# Python Remove duplicates and original from nested list based on specific key

Tags: python, list, duplicates, nested-lists

I m trying to delete all duplicates & original from a nested list based on specific column.

Example

```
list = [['abc',3232,'demo text'],['def',9834,'another text'],['abc',0988,'another another text'],['poi',1234,'text']]
```

The key column is the first (abc, def, abc) and based on this I want to remove any item (plus the original) which has the same value with the original.

So the new list should contain:

```
newlist = [['def',9834,'another text'],['poi',1234,'text']]
```

I found many similar topics but not for nested lists...
Any help please?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Side point. Never name a variable after a built-in, use `L` or `list_` instead of `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [['abc',3232,'demo text'],['def',9834,'another text'],['abc',988,'another another text'],['poi',1234,'text']]

d = dict(Counter(x[0] for x in lst))
print([x for x in lst if d[x[0]] == 1])

# [['def', 9834, 'another text'], 
#  ['poi', 1234, 'text']]
```

Also note that you shouldn't name your list as `list` as it shadows the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: Good solution, this has O(n) complexity. But I don't think `if x[0] in d.keys()` is necessary?

Comment: @jpp oops! That isn't necessary. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a list of keys

```
keys = [x[0] for x in list]
```

and select only those records for which the key occurs exactly once

```
newlist = [x for x in list if keys.count(x[0]) == 1]
```

Comment: You have O(n^2) complexity here by calling `list.count` n times. You could use `collections.Counter` to make this O(n). Or store your counts separately.

Comment: Well, OP didn't say anything regarding the list size, so I assumed it is not large enough to make the difference between O(n) and O(n^2). Definitely, using `Counter` is more efficient approach but I intended to give a quick-and-dirty solution that works well in most cases.

Comment: My comment isn't a complaint, it's just a note which may interest readers.

Comment: No offense taken;) Just explained my intent.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension.

**Demo:**

```
l = [['abc',3232,'demo text'],['def',9834,'another text'],['abc', 988,'another another text'],['poi',1234,'text']]
checkVal = [i[0] for i in l]
print( [i for i in l if not checkVal.count(i[0]) > 1 ] )
```

**Output:**

```
[['def', 9834, 'another text'], ['poi', 1234, 'text']]
```

Comment: You have O(n^2) complexity here by calling `list.count` n times. You could use `collections.Counter` to make this O(n). Or store your counts separately.

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.defaultdict` for an O(n) solution:

```
L = [['abc',3232,'demo text'],
     ['def',9834,'another text'],
     ['abc',988,'another another text'],
     ['poi',1234,'text']]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for key, num, txt in L:
    d[key].append([num, txt])

res = [[k, *v[0]] for k, v in d.items() if len(v) == 1]

print(res)

[['def', 9834, 'another text'],
 ['poi', 1234, 'text']]
```

Comment: Between this solution is also good. I usually go for `Counter` than a `defaultdict` way. +1.